# I force pushed my git repository by mistake

Tags: github, reset, github-desktop

My .git folder is corrupted, Github Desktop detects that repo is new. I was searching about how i can push the new changes i found this command `git push -f origin master`. I executed it by mistake, it resets the repo history

I didn't expect that behaviour, is there any method how i can reset my old repo history ?

Comment: You could try pulling a previous commit and going from there, provided the server-side repo is still in tact